# amp analytics missing pageviewId64

Tags: amp-html, amp-analytics

I am trying to send some analytics data using **amp-analytics** component but for some reason, the packet is missing **pageViewId64**, I am getting **pageViewId**.

Minimal code to test- (Add amp-analytics component in the head if not already added)

```
<amp-analytics>
<script type="application/json">
{
"requests": {
  "pageview": "api-endpoint"
},
"transport": {
   "xhrpost": true,
   "useBody": true,
   "beacon": false
 },
 "extraUrlParams": {
    "pageViewId":"${pageViewId}",
    "pageViewId64":"${pageViewId64}",
    "timezone":"${timezoneCode}",
    "domain":"${ampdocHostname}"
},
"triggers": {
        "trackPageview": {
          "on": "visible",
          "request": "pageview"
        }
      }
}
</script>
</amp-analytics>
```

Request snapshot -
[image]

Is there something that I am missing over here.?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to use **pageViewId64** by directly using the platform variable - **PAGE_VIEW_ID_64** rather than looking for amp-analytics variable (**${pageViewId64}**)

i.e. -

```
vars: {
  pageViewId64: "PAGE_VIEW_ID_64",
}
```

Another way is to assign platform variable to a var so that you can use it the usual way - *${pageViewId64}*

Request snapshot with direct platform variable -

[image]